# Issue in forming RDD of vectors to pass to Pysparks Correlation function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, correlation

I am trying to do `pairwise correlation` in `Pyspark`. I am reading the input file and then forming a `dataframe` out of it. Now to pass it to `pyspark`s correlations function I need to convert it into an `rdd of vectors`. Here is my current code:

```
    input = sc.textFile('File1.csv')
    header = input.first()  # extract header
    data = input.filter(lambda x: x != header)
    parsedInput = data.map(lambda l: l.split(","))

    # define schema
    schemaString = "col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12"
    fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split()]
    schema = StructType(fields)

    df_i = sqlContext.createDataFrame(parsedInput, schema)
```

Now as per `pyspark` document at [this page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/mllib-statistics.html#correlations) this is the way to calculate correlations:

```
data = ... # an RDD of Vectors
print(Statistics.corr(data, method="pearson"))
```

How can I convert my `dataframe` `df_i` to form a `RDD of vectors` so that I can pass it to `corr()`?

Also if there a better way (than what I have so far now) to read input file and do a pairwise correlation on that file using pyspark then please do show me with an example.

**UPDATE:** Here is a sample input of my data:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,160,408,3387232,no,no,0,82.7,116,0.712931034
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,90,408,3683931,no,yes,39,94.8,89,1.065168539
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,104,408,3663917,no,no,0,183.6,133,1.380451128
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,96,408,3292045,no,no,0,144,102,1.411764706
Cameroon,25 - 39 years old,8,126,408,3399798,yes,no,0,197.6,126,1.568253968
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,146,408,3483581,no,no,0,109,69,1.579710145
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,34,408,3396446,no,no,0,128.8,80,1.61
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,93,408,3607246,no,yes,42,166.9,101,1.652475248
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,42,408,3577060,no,no,0,146.3,84,1.741666667
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,57,408,3573817,no,yes,39,213,115,1.852173913
Cameroon,15 - 24 years old,8,94,408,3444022,no,no,0,207,109,1.899082569
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6308/how-to-convert-a-sqlcontext-dataframe-to-rdd-of-vectors-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

result = df_i
 .rdd # converts DataFrame to RDD of Rows 
 .map(lambda row : Vectors.dense([item for item in row])
```

where I've assumed every column value in your DataFrame is needed from each `Row` (hence the `item for item in row` call).

Relevant example of how an RDD of vectors looks like is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.stat.Statistics.corr). Relevant documentation for `.rdd` is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.rdd).

Comment: Some of my data contains string and it is throwing error for such data. How can I get that resolved? I have posted a sample input of my data in my post above

Comment: Then you have to filter out elements that aren't integers or convert the string elements to integers somehow. If you want the first option, replace `[item for item in row]` with `filter(lambda item: item is int, row)` or to whatever the datatype you have in your DataFrame.

Comment: That still won't work @AkshatMahajan with strings. The OP needs to index his strings and create a dictionary. Then he'll be able to apply your solution. He can read about it in the spark-ml documentation about features extractions.

Comment: @eliasah: I meant that OP should either keep only numeric entries or convert non-numeric entries to numeric form somehow. I don't think it makes sense to try and keep strings in a vector, especially when you're trying to calculate Pearson correlation. Is what you're proposing substantially different?

Comment: I never said to keep strings in vectors but this how the processed is defined in spark-ml. Strings must be split then converted into numeric values which can be used in vectors afterwards.

Comment: @eliasah Why split a string? It's sufficient to define a function to handle string conversion to int for you if you want to capture only special characters in the string. You're right, they have to be converted, but splitting first is only one possible way to do it - another is a list comprehension keeping only numeric characters in the string.